# Parent process receives KeyboardInterrupt on subsequent read() when child process is sent a signal

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Working with Python 3.7 on MacOS:

I have a multiprocessing pool in which subprocesses handle units of work.

In turn, each of these Pool child processes must run a command subprocess, which is done using Popen; for example:

```py
    with Popen([CMD, ARGS], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, encoding='utf8', close_fds=True, cwd=JSBOT_DIR, start_new_session=True, ) as process:
        try:
            while process.poll() is None:
                (ready, _, error) = select([process_stdout], [], [process_stdout], timeout)
                if process_stdout in ready:
                    line = process_stdout.readline()
                    while line:
                        LOGGER.info(f'{line.rstrip()}')
                        line = process_stdout.readline()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            LOGGER.info('Got KeyboardInterrupt from subprocess')
        # ...
        process.wait(10)
```

This command subprocess may be signaled that it is time to wrap up and exit by sending it a SIGUSR2.

Once this command subprocess is completed, there is some post-processing that takes place.  This is achieved using `subprocess.run` in the Pool child, for example:

```py
            result = subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', pathname, '-ac', '1', '-ar', '48000', '-c:a', 'pcm_s16le',
                                     normalized_filename], stderr=STDOUT, stdout=PIPE)
```

The problem I am having is that immediately upon the execution of `subprocess.run()`, Python issues a KeyboardInterrupt, and the **Pool** child dies immediately:

```py
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 474, in run
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 926, in communicate
    stdout = self.stdout.read()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I've tried setting SIGUSR2 and SIGINT to be certain to be ignored in the Pool child process during child initialization; however, this hasn't helped.  I've also tried with and without start_new_session=True.  I've also tried setting SIGINT to be handled in the Pool child, but the handler is not called when this happens.  The handler IS called if I deliberately send the Pool child a SIGINT.

If I make the process just `time.sleep(10)` prior to trying to create the next process, it will sleep the full time, and then immediately believe a KeyboardInterrupt has arrived upon the first read inside `subprocess.run`.

The behavior *appears* to be such that delivering a signal to the Pool child's command subprocess causes Python to believe that a KeyboardInterrupt has been sent to the Pool child, and this KeyboardInterrupt is handled upon the first IO attempt.

My questions are: why is this happening (ie, what did I miss?), and how do I prevent this from happening?

I also noticed that I catch and log a KeyboardInterrupt inside the command subprocess context when the Popened command terminates.  Could this be a case of the interpreter 'remembering' that there's a pending KeyboardInterrupt which ends up being handled later on?  If so, how might I suppress it or 'clear' the KeyboardInterrupt?

EDIT: As I've continued to play around with this, I found that if I comment out all of the select/readline/log loop, everything works fine.  So it appears to be the act of reading something from the command subprocess that's killing the Pool child.

Comment: You run `with Popen([CMD, ARGS]...` inside the multiprocessing pool, right ? have you tried handling the `KeyboardInterrupt` inside the main function/main process ?

Comment: That is correct. One of the pool workers is calling Popen. The main process never sees the KeyboardInterrupt, but the pool worker is killed by it.  Tomorrow I'll add some tracebacks to see where the KeyboardInterrupt is originating in the pool worker. It has to be coming from poll, select, or readline, and it must be getting generated when the Popened process exits.

Comment: I came in today with a plan to really get to the bottom of this, but it mysteriously stopped happening!  It was happening 100% of the time last night, but today it is happening 0% of the time, without any intervening code changes.